# Versions of inheritance in java with casting

Tags: java, inheritance, casting

I am a bit confused with the following exercise and didn't find that kind of question with the search function.

which of these alternatives are executable, given that :

```
class Animal
class Dog extends Animal   //Dog is an extension of Animal
```

We want to assign an object of class `Dog` to an variable of type `Animal`:

```
(1) Animal t = new Object();
(2) Animal t = (Dog) (new Object());
(3) Animal t = new Dog();
(4) Animal t = (Dog) new Class();
```

1. *wrong* : is wrong because it has nothing to do with dog.
2. *good* : Object is upperclass to Dog, we cast it to Dog which extends animal, so its okay.
3. *good* : it's okay too, because every Dog is an animal.
4. *wrong* : new Class is not defiend, so its wrong.

Is my reasoning right? I am thankful for every help.

Comment: You could test this pretty easily, no?

Comment: Im not going to give you an answer to your question, but the magic keyword you want search for is `java polymorphism`

Comment: An object’s class is a quality of the object itself.  No matter what you cast it to, you are not changing the object’s class, only how your code chooses to view that class.  If the object you create isn’t of a class which inherits from Animal, casting will not make it an Animal.

Comment: @OHGODSPIDERS is this just for Object or generell?, e. g. Animal A = (Dog) new Pet(); where Dog extends Pet and Pet extents Animal?

Comment: @VGR so the only way casting make sense is Dog D= (Dog) XYZ (XYZ is upperclass) ?

Comment: If and only if Pet inherits from Dog, you may cast it to Dog.

Comment: @PeterPan You can only cast to something that the object actually is. Casting does not "convert" anything it only changes how an already existing Object is treated. So you can cast a Dog to an Animal, but never the other way around. You can however do the Following: `Object obj = new Dog(); Dog dog = (Dog) obj;` because obj already is a Dog and was only assigned to a variable of type Object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not tried them but I think:

```
(1) Animal t = new Object();
```

**invalid - an `Object` is not an `Animal` - will not compile**

```
(2) Animal t = (Dog) (new Object());
```

**invalid - an `Object` is not an `Animal` - will compile but will fail at run time**

```
(3) Animal t = new Dog();
```

*fine - a `Dog` is an `Animal`*

```
(4) Animal t = (Dog) new Class();
```

**this is the same as (2) - are you certain you copied it right?**

Comment: Yes, I did. It's probably one of the easier questions, but I was very confused, especially whith (2) and (3). Thank y you.